# Java/SeleniumWebDriver - Click a JQuery dialog button with Selenium

Tags: java, jquery, selenium

I currently trying to test a dialog with Selenium WebDriver but the "Create Employee" button doesn't  have an id nor a name. This is what the code looks like.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">

         <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
              <span class="ui-button-text">Create Employee</span>
         </button>

         <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
              <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
         </button>

    </div>

         <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
              <span class="ui-button-text">Create Employee</span>
         </button>

         <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
              <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
         </button>

</div>
```

Can anyone provide me with the java code that will click the button in the dialog box? Thanks

Comment: Hey from above html page i guessing there are two buttons with same name as 'Create Employee' am i right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Below code.

```
 driver.findelement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']/span[text()='Create Employee']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the xpath stuff, which I found troublesome for newbies, I found that jQueryUI dialog can add IDs to the results.

Instead of:

```
$("#stuff").dialog({
    buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
```

write:

```
$("#stuff").dialog({
    buttons: {
            "Yes": { text: "Yes",
                     id: "#mystuff-yes",
                     click: function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any way to select any element I would suggest the use of `xpath`
I would suggest installing some addons or extensions on your browser for getting the `xpath` of the element you want to interact. Then Use that xpath for your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

If your text does not change, you can use:

```
$('.ui-button-text').click(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'Create Employee') {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V2wVv/)**

Comment: I already have the code. I just need to test it using Selenium WebDriver to submit a form.